# Which altcoins have their own mobile friendly wallet created by the core devs?

Tags: wallet, altcoin

Was wondering how many coins have their core wallet software that is accessible on mobile devices? 3rd party devs do not count.

Only want a list of coins that can be used on mobile devices as this reduces the risk of theft as the wallet software is made by the core devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXT has a mobile app wallet which is a port of the platform web wallet to an Html5 WebView running on Andoroid and i/OS using the Apache Cordova technology

Comment: link or screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

[The Dogecoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.langerhans.wallet&hl=en) was created by Max Keller, who is the lead developer for Dogecoin.

This [Litecoin Wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet_ltc&hl=en) purports to be created by a third party developer who "teamed up with the Litecoin Dev Team". I'm not sure if that counts for your purposes.

Comment: Isn't Dogecoin Wallet just a rebranded version of Bitcoin Wallet for Android?

Comment: @PieterWuille: Pretty sure it is.